# How to retrieve boolean value from php to javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

is that possible to retrieve Boolean value from php to javascript?

All I want to do is simple: Retrieve Boolean value from php variable `$x` into js

> 1. Should be **true** **when emails are sent**
> 2. And **False** when **emails are not sent**

Then take that Boolean value with **javascript** print the appropriate message

Complete code of my work can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45438333/detect-php-mailer-error-and-print-the-message-in-the-website-using-jquery), on my other case I had opened yesterday

**PHP:**

```
if (!$mail->send()) {
   $x = false; //when email is not sent
} else {
    $x = true; //when email is sent
}
```

**JS Pseudocode**

```
.done(function (data) {
    if(php Boolean variable is false) { 
        ("$formText").html("Message sent");
    } else (if php Boolean variable is true) {
        ("$formText").html("Message not sent");
    }
});
```

Comment: What you're looking for is called `AJAX`

Comment: or define your javascript variable in a php executable file then call that variable from your js file

Comment: It would be helpful to post an answer of your thoughts, don't worry I won't down vote if they won't work :)

Comment: @Eternal Are you posting your from through ajax ?

Comment: @SaadSuri yes look the complete code in the link I posted in my question

Comment: in that case, why do you want to use boolean and not http_response_code for success or error? easier to handle i think

Comment: can you post your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are already passing data (via AJAX) you just don't know how to encode it.

Use: `json_encode()`

PHP:

```
if (!$mail->send()) {
$x = true;

} else {
 $x = false;
}
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode(array('x'=>$x));
```

Javascript:

```
 .done(function (data) {
           if (data.x) { 
               $("#formText").html("Message sent");
           } else {
               $("#formText").html("Message not sent");
           }
        } //end function data      
  );//end done function
```

Comment: yes I am using ajax, look the complete code in the link I posted in my question

Comment: make sure set `dataType: 'json'` also and/or send proper content type header

Comment: your else is missing the open {

Comment: Nice but it works only when the emails are sent. Nothing happens when emails aren't sent

Comment: Is it because I switched the `true` and `false` from your code? `$x = true` should have been `$x = false` in my code.

Comment: It doesn't matter. The thing is in php,  the variable `$x`  only works in the else statement of the php code. Nothing happens in the if. So only when emails are sent, the message is printed

Comment: I don't know maybe it is a mistake in js?

Comment: If you're saying the variable `$x` only works in the `else` statement of the PHP code, then it's because `$mail->send()` always returns true. Maybe look there.

Comment: well the php works, I get false when email not send and true when sent but in javascript it only prints the else part.

Comment: Maybe data is not a javascript object. Try this: `$('#formText').html(typeof data);` and check if it says `object`. Are you using jQuery? Did you send the header in PHP? Try forcing jQuery to parse the response by passing `{"dataType":"json"}` in the settings of your `$.ajax()` request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150835/discussion-between-eternal-and-fredster).

Answer (score 0):

While returning bool value from PHP code use json_encode(). It convert from native PHP types to native Javascript type.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

using response code and handling them with done and fail

PHP

```
<?php
  // ...

  $success = '{"message": "your mail is send"}';
  $error = '{"message": "failed sending mail"}';

  $code;
  $out;
  if(mailSend){
    $code = 200;
    $out = $success;
  } else {
    $code = 400;
    $out = $error;
  }

  http_response_code($code);
  echo $out;
```

JS

```
// ...
var data = 'yourData';

$.ajax({
  url: 'yourApiUrl'M,
  data: data,
  method: 'POST',
  xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: 'json'
}).done(function() {
  // mail was send
}).fail(function() {
  // error on sending
});
```

a list of status codes you can find on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: url to api  you mean php file path ?

Comment: something is not working properly and the page reloads

Comment: @Eternal, url is the domain you can attache your php script through. bacause php is server based the relative path to the file only works if it's in the same base base folder as the the js file

Comment: no it doesn't matter, I am using ../phpfile.php and works